# send email via asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, email

Im looking to send email vi a .net 3.5 form (C#)

Ive seen a few posts elsewhere and got the thing running ok for certain addresses but not for others, eg gmail accounts.
The finished app will have to pick up addresses from a database so Im having to cater for a lot of possibilites.
Im not looking to have my work done for me, just a shove in the right direction would be cool!

thanks

DD

Comment: We'd better see the code that's failing and try and fix it, can you post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible the gmail accounts are blocking you as a spammer? If you're sending out a lot of emails, or if there is a configuraiton issue on your server, they may have blacklisted you.

If the emails are going out from your server OK, but not reaching ALL of the recipients but is reaching SOME, then there is likely an issue outside of your direct control. An email goes through several servers in between your server and the enduser's inbox (and that's the case even if the inbox is on google's server for gmail.)

That said, there are things you can do to reduce your likelihood of being blocked/blacklisted.

This is a good place to start:  http://www.andreas-kraus.net/blog/tips-for-avoiding-spam-filters-with-systemnetmail/

and then here is where to go from there.  (Sorry - it's just a google search, but I gave you the relevant terms, at least.)  http://www.google.com/search?q=system.net.mail+blacklist+spammer&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1

Finally, here's a very good resource with a cool URL.  Perhaps the force will be with you if you learn these ways, young padawan.

http://www.emaildeliveryjedi.com/avoid-spam-filters.php

But getting back to your original question - everything you need to know about how to write code to send an email is covered here: http://www.systemnetmail.com/  It's the same for all versions of .NET from 2.0 on uo through the current 4.0.

And I'm sure you're already aware, but in case you're not, be sure you're familiar with the CAN-SPAM act.  http://business.ftc.gov/documents/bus61-can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the great info from David Stratton...If you're certain that the gmail accounts are not receiving your emails, i.e. you've waited for sometime, checked the gmail spam boxes, and you've checked your SMTP server logs to ensure that Google is not sending any particular messages back to your SMTP server, then you may have run into a case of grey-listing / black-listing.

Black-listing can occur when a mail service has decided that the IP address of your mail server is a spamming server. It can happen under different scenarios, shared scenarios can be quite common.

One shared scenario: Let's say you recently acquired a new IP address, but it was recycled by your hosting provider from a prior client of theirs, who was a spammer. There is no guarantee that the IP address would be white-listed.

Another shared scenario: You're sending emails on a shared hosting website, where your SMTP service that you are using is shared with other clients of the SMTP service provider. It may be that one of those clients used the SMTP service maliciously or without following appropriate SPAM rules that gmail abides by.

Your best bet is to contact Google to commence a white-listing process. Providing you follow their requirements, they should eventually unblock emails originating from your service.