# How to send email from code ?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491651/how-to-send-an-email)

I have some simple winform application. 
In some place in the flow the user have button that if he will press on it the application will send email to some know mail address.

How can i implement this ? 
How can i send the mail ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are many threads in SO on this. Why dont you search before starting a thread?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+send+email

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491651/how-to-send-an-email), or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028728/c-how-to-send-email , or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458042/send-email-using-asp-net-and-c, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796224/send-email-via-asp-net-3-5 , the list is almost endless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the System.Net.Mail namespace and the SmtpClient class:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

FAQ site with good samples.

http://www.systemnetmail.com/